# Can changing the array length directly produce bugs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an app where the redux state has a field called data that's null initially, then when uploading something it changes to an array of objects and the reducer uses delete to remove an object when we press the required button. But that doesn't change the length of the array so it causes an uncaught error. The simplest solution would be to simply change the length of the array after we delete that object. Can this produce any bugs?

EDIT: This is the code:

```
case actions.RIR:
            const filtered = [...state.data];
            delete filtered[action.payload];
            filtered.length--; // this has been added by me
            return {...state, data: [...filtered]};
```

The original code isn't mine. It's part of a project. I've been asked to fix an error.

Comment: Why not `splice()` instead of `delete`?

Comment: how do you remove from this array? please share some code

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen if this a redux state were taling about, splicing should be done very carefuly, only after copying the old array. `filter` is a prefferable choice since it doesnt mutate the original array

Comment: @MorKadosh Fair point, but if OP is using `delete`, that also mutates the array... However it may be, cannot say anything definitive until some code is presented.

Comment: @LiviuGanea I would stick to [immutable update patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays) advised by redux so don't use delete on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

First one foremost, reducers should be pure - meaning - no side effects.
`delete` is a side effect since it mutates an original object.
In reducers, use immutable patterns - either use `filter`, or `splice` a copy of the original array (less recomended).
Besides that, `delete` will simply make this element `undefined`, and your array will look like:

`['item 1','item 2'....,empty,'item n']`

I would write it:

```
case actions.RIR:
            const filtered = state.data.filter(item => item !== action.payload);
            return {...state, data: filtered};
```

Or whatever filter logic you might require.